# Dynamically Changing and Saving Content in Text Box

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, mysql

I am trying to create a web page that has something akin to a blog editor functionality. I want the user to be able to define their font style (basic categories like header 1, 2, 3, default text, etc.). I was planning on just using a HTML text box tag with a drop down menu that the user can use to toggle their text style.

I am not sure, however, how to change the style of the text that the user puts in the text box and then save the user's post (with styling preferences) in a MySQL database.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, it seems like your question needs to be more focused to get some good answers, right now you are asking about a few different things in just the one question. Please have a look at the [ask] section to get some ideas. I recommend that you look at some tutorials online and give it a try first.

Comment: If you took the second paragraph out of your question, leaving only the first. And added a sample of what you have tried so far, and where you got stuck, I think you would get some good answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use tools below that designed specially for your need.

- [Editor.js](https://editorjs.io/)
- [WYSIWYG](https://froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/)
- [ContentTools](http://getcontenttools.com/)
- [Aloha Editor](https://www.alohaeditor.org/)
- [summernote](https://summernote.org/)
- [CKEditor](https://ckeditor.com/)
- [Trumbowyg](https://alex-d.github.io/Trumbowyg/)
- [Redactor](https://imperavi.com/redactor/)